# Why am I getting a syntax error for a colon in python?

Tags: python

```
def retry():
    print("type Y to retry, type N to exit")
    rr = (input(:  )).lower()
    if rr == "y":
        rdl1()
    if rr == "n":
        exit()
```

I am getting this error

```
File "randomriddle.py", line 5
rr = (input(:  )).lower()
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That's just not valid syntax. What did you expect that to do? Did you want to print a colon?

Comment: Try: `rr = input(':').lower()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
rr = (input(:  )).lower()
```

with :

```
rr = (input(":  ")).lower()
```

Comment: thank you so much, i just looked over that.